# Can I set view data without returning the view in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I have got a template called `structure` in the folder `components` with header and footer elements. All my views are child of this one. So, in the header, I want to check if the user is logged to display a box dialogue.

So, I have got this code in the parent view:

```
<div class="loginDialogue">
                            {{-- {{$logged = false}} --}}
                            @if ($logged == true)
                            <a href="/profile" class="navbarBtn">Ver perfil de {{$userId}}</a>
                            <a href="/carrito" class="navbarBtn">Ver carrito</a>

                            @else
                            <a href="/login" class="navbarBtn">Iniciar sesión</a>
                            <a href="/registrer" class="navbarBtn">Registrarse</a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
```

And this is the controller code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $logged = true;
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;

        view('components.structure')
            ->with('userId', $userId)
            ->with('logged', $logged);
        return view('index');
    } else {
        $logged = false;
        $userId = "";
        view('components.structure')
            ->with('logged', $logged)
            ->with('userId', $userId);
        return view('index');
    }
});
```

My problem is the `$logged` appears as `undefined` and I was looking for information about pass data to a view without returning it, but I found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to send authentication data to the view

```
<div class="loginDialogue">
      
      @if (Auth::check())
            <a href="/profile" class="navbarBtn">Ver perfil de {{Auth::id()}}</a>
            <a href="/carrito" class="navbarBtn">Ver carrito</a>

      @else
         <a href="/login" class="navbarBtn">Iniciar sesión</a>
         <a href="/registrer" class="navbarBtn">Registrarse</a>
      @endif
 </div>

Route::get('/', function () {
    
        return view('index');
    }
});
```

Comment: So, I guess I can work with Auth class into blade templates, right?

Comment: yes. you can also use auth() helper function

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about auth info then you dont have to pass it through controller.

```
<div class="loginDialogue">
    @if (auth()->check())
        <a href="/profile" class="navbarBtn">Ver perfil de {{auth()->id()}}</a>
        <a href="/carrito" class="navbarBtn">Ver carrito</a>
    @else
        <a href="/login" class="navbarBtn">Iniciar sesión</a>
        <a href="/registrer" class="navbarBtn">Registrarse</a>
    @endif
</div>
```